# How can I trim the entire select statement in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a long Select statement:

```
select a, b,  c, d, ... etc from tableA;
```

How would I be able to trim all of the above without writing:

```
select trim(a), trim(b) etc ...
```

I am fine implementing this either in the SQL Server or in C# if there is an easier way? Any creative ideas such as using a for each loop or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the use case, performance and bandwidth considerations, one thing you might do is do it in C# like that:

You get the query results back to your code (be it an EF IQueryable, ADO.NET DataTable etc.) and you iterate through the fields, checking whether a given field is of a `String` type, for which you apply `.Trim()` on.

Answer (score 0):

Build up a tool set of string manipulation functions to help you do mundane tasks that you do often.  Save them as procedures or functions on your server or write a program and call on them as needed to help you build queries.  For example to wrap all columns in functions:

```
declare @stringlist as varchar(max)
declare @stringlistnew as varchar(max)
declare @wrapstart as varchar(max)
declare @wrapend as varchar(max)

set @stringlist = 'a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i'
set @wrapstart = 'ltrim(rtrim('
set @wrapend = ')) '

declare @i as int
set @i=0
set @stringlist = ltrim(@stringlist) + ','

while LEN(@stringlist) > 1
begin
    set @i=charindex(',',@stringlist)
    set @stringlistnew = case when ISNULL(@stringlistnew, '') = '' then '' else @stringlistnew + ', ' end
    set @stringlistnew = @stringlistnew + @wrapstart + ltrim(rtrim(LEFT(@stringlist,@i-1))) + @wrapend + ltrim(rtrim(LEFT(@stringlist,@i-1)))
    set @stringlist = ltrim(RIGHT(@stringlist, len(@stringlist)-@i))
end

select @stringlistnew stringlistnew
```

You can get a list of columns from management studio by outputting a query to text.  Copy the table header and paste into a new window and search and replace double spaces with a single space and repeat until you have only one space between each column name.  Then replace all space with a comma.  Or you could modify this function to do all that for you as well.  :)